# Hide upload forms

Tags: jquery, forms, file-upload

I have an form, and I need to hide on a certain action hide all the upload forms. How can I do this in jQuery? Thanks!

```
<h2>Please fill in the file-upload form below</h2>
<form action="fup.cgi" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
File to upload:
<input type="file" name="upfile">
<br>
Notes about the file:
<input type="text" name="note">
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Press">
to upload the file!
</form>
<hr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should word:

```
$('input:file').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the form and header tag in a `<div id="myform">` then with jQuery you can use

```
$('#myform').hide();
```

or

```
$('#myform').show();
```

You can get all the information you need and examples looking at the [jQuery API: Hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)